# Is it worthwhile to store my supply chain product data on the blockchain using a smart contract?

Tags: web3j, java, android

I'm currently developing an android app that uses the **Web3j** framework (Java) to interact with my private Ethereum blockchain (running on Ganache). The app is a supply chain tool that will let users create orders for products and use Ethereum for creating transactions to ensure immutability and traceability.

Is there a good reason to store the product data/records (i.e. product name,description) on a smart contract that I can request using the Web3j framework in my app, or should I just use a standard database?

Comment: Just know all the data in ethereum blockchain will be public. So not to store any sensitive information, or you can hash them and store with caution.

Answer (score 2):

As is the case with many blockchain business ideas you should really consider why you want to use blockchain for your use and why exactly you need a blockchain. All too often the end result of this is "I actually don't need a blockchain but it still sounds cool".

Furthermore with a private blockchain it might be questionable how immutable your data is. Depending on your (desired) setup you probably control the blockchain and its miners and can therefore simply control the data in the blockchain - nothing prevents you from reverting a bunch of blocks and mining a new chain starting from some block. Therefore you may encounter trust issues.